# TypeError: float() argument must be string or number, not '_NoValueType'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Just started learning Python3.7. Currently using Spyder as the developer and am trying to generate plots with matplotlib.  Unfortunately, I continue to receive the following message:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_NoVAlueType'

Code worked fine a few days ago but, now seems unreadable just shortly after I updated to Spyder 4.0.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]

y = [2, 4, 1]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel('X - axis')

plt.ylabel('y - axis')

plt.title('My first graph')

plt.show()
```

and here is the output:
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_NoValueType'

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I executed your code in Googe Colab and the code seems to be completely fine. Could you elaborate on which line exactly do you get this error on?

Comment: Thanks for the response Saurav.  I went ahead and reinstalled Anaconda as well as updated Spyder to the most recent version.  That seemed to do the trick.  Code runs without any issue now.

Comment: Good to know :)